# Determining when Relay is fetching query data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm using Reactjs and Relayjs in my web application. One of the pages, I call it `memberList`, is displaying a list of all users registered on the website.

This is a simplified version of my implementation:

```
render() {
  {this.props.memberList.edges.length > 0 ? 
    <ol>
      {this.props.memberList.edges.map(
        (member, i) => {
          return <li>{member.node.username}</li>;
        }
      )}
    </ol>
  : <span>No members to show!</span>}
}
```

And my RelayContainer:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(MemberList, {
  fragments: {
    classroom: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Classroom {
        id,
        memberList(first: 100) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              username
            }
          }
        },
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

This works fine; it displays all the members of the classroom as expected. However, the page doesn't behave quite as I'd like it to:

- When navigating to the page, or when refreshing, the `<span>` is rendered for a brief moment, because the `this.props.memberList.edges` array is empty.
- Less than one second later, the `props` update and the array is no longer empty. This causes a re-render and the `<ul>` list with the members is now displayed instead - as expected.

I want to know when Relay is fetching data so I can determine if the `memberList` is *actually* empty or if its' properties cannot yet be determined because a query response is pending.

How can this be accomplished? I've searched for over 2 hours and I can only find relevant answers to mutations, which is not what I'm doing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that your component is briefly rendering the `span`. By default the component shouldn't even be rendered if Relay hasn't finished fetching data.

Anyway, if you figure out what is going on there, `Relay.Renderer` has a [`render` prop](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-renderer.html#render) that you can use to achieve what you want. Here's an example (taken directly from the docs).

In this example, `ErrorComponent` and `LoadingComponent` simply display a static error message / loading indicator.

```
<Relay.Renderer
  Container={ProfilePicture}
  queryConfig={profileRoute}
  environment={Relay.Store}
  render={({done, error, props, retry, stale}) => {
    if (error) {
      return <ErrorComponent />;
    } else if (props) {
      return <ProfilePicture {...props} />;
    } else {
      return <LoadingComponent />;
    }
  }}
/>
```

If you're using `Relay.RootContainer`, it has some a similar `renderLoading` prop.